# how to set custom field of all workitems in Polarion

Tags: javascript, polarion

There are over 30000 work items, making it difficult to write the setCustomFields() method on the code.
Is there a way to change the custom field value of all existing work items?

i tried to use method queryWorkItems() and setCustomField()
but it took super long time